# Create multi domain vendor script in php

Tags: php, joomla, subdomain, vendor

i want to create a multi vendor domain script in PHP. I have wondered all the places but nothing found yet. It is possible to create multi vendor domain with one site. I have a site and in this site there lots of user will create own site. if user logged in vendor id then they will able to create our own domain. like user.site-name.com. so it this possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to split admin and display procedure.

Admin part would be a custom php cms that would give user options for article management, categories management, etc. This would be same for all users with admin levels.

The frontend (display) script would be located in another folder and display the appropriate data for each client instance.

Subdomain creation could be done with [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) rules so instead of a folder domain.com/user1 you would display the data as user1.domain.com.

Hope this helps